# Howto store vectors in database: BLOB or ARRAY?

Tags: database, vector, blob

I will soon need to store measurements (from within MATLAB) in a database - maybe MySQL.
Each measurement will consist of some let's say meta-data and a measurement vector of 4096 float (double) entries.
Which way should I store them into the database? Converting then into a `BLOB` or taking them as an `ARRAY` type column? I found those column type within [JAVA jdbc Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html).
Any hints are welcome - even different solutions.

Comment: Note that MySQL does not have array types, when you make your choice of engine. The choice of storage method depends more on what you're going to do with that data once it is in the database, than on the way you want to store it.

Comment: @lanzz Thankyou for your note. I just need to decide, what would be better (looking further into the future): With blobs - you always need to convert your data. Thus using arrays of double precision floats (DOUBLE columns) might be easier - but indeed the fewest dbms support arrays.   So what to do? Will more and more dbms support arrays in the future?

Comment: Arrays are defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, so it is likely that more DBMS will adopt support for them over time instead of the other way around. You are likely to need _some_ conversion even when using arrays, as arrays results are usually encoded as a string representation, which will need to be parsed, though that shouldn't be a problem with a simple 1-dimensional array of doubles.

Comment: It makes sense to use arrays, if you intend to operate on the vector contents _on the server_, e.g. to search for values (`:value = ANY (array_column)`). If you're _only_ going to retrieve the vector, without inspecting its contents directly in queries, it won't matter that much what storage you decide on. Actually you might benefit from blob/text storage in order to avoid any additional processing on the DBMS side (i.e. the encoding of the array value as a string representation for the result).

Comment: @lanzz okay, your lines clearly show up the situation. Please post that as an answer for giving me the possibility to accept that. THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that MySQL does not have array types, when you make your choice of engine. Arrays are defined in the ANSI/ISO SQL standard, so it is likely that more DBMS will adopt support for them over time instead of the other way around.

You are likely to need *some* conversion even when using arrays, as arrays results are usually encoded as a string representation, which will need to be parsed, though that shouldn't be a problem with a simple 1-dimensional array of doubles. The choice of storage method depends more on what you're going to do with that data once it is in the database, than on the way you want to store it.

It makes sense to use arrays, if you intend to operate on the vector contents *on the server*, e.g. to search for values (`:value = ANY (array_column)`). If you're *only* going to retrieve the vector, without inspecting its contents directly in queries, it won't matter that much what storage you decide on. Actually you might benefit from blob/text storage in order to avoid any additional processing on the DBMS side (i.e. the encoding of the array value as a string representation for the result).